# Navigating between ContentPages with Prism in Xamarin Forms maintains NavigationParameters

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

Using the NavigationParameters collection within Prism, we are passing an object from one ContentPage to another ContentPage which displays as a modal.

The modal allows a user to edit the data. If the user decides to cancel the edit form, we call:

```
NavigationService.GoBackAsync(null, true).
```

Once navigated back to the previous page, the original property that was passed through to the modal has updated with the edited values without setting it.

Are NavigationParameters passed as a reference within NavigateAsync? What’s the best way of preventing this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the NavigationParameters collection within Prism, we are passing an **object** [...] [Emphasis mine]

You are setting an object in the `NavigationParameters`. Instances of classes (objects) are passed by reference in C#, instances of structures are passed by value. For structures there are semantics to copy and compare values (i.e. all public properties are copied and compared respectively), but for classes there are no similar semantics.

Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects):

> Because classes are reference types, a variable of a class object holds a reference to the address of the object on the managed heap. If a second object of the same type is assigned to the first object, then both variables refer to the object at that address.

In order to prevent the original object being updated, you'll have to *copy* the object before it is manipulated (I'd copy it before passing it, but you could copy it at the target site, too). If your class contains value type properties only, a shallow copy will suffice, i.e. you create a method (or property, but this might be misleading) that returns a new object of your class with all the values copied

```
class MyClass
{
    int Value1 { get; set; }
    float Value2 { get; set; }

    public MyClass Copy()
    {
        var copy = new MyClass()
                       {
                           Value1 = this.Value1,
                           Value2 = this.Value2
                       }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

If you object contains reference types itself, you might have to create a deep copy

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass2 Reference { get; set; }

    public MyClass Copy()
    {
        var copy = new MyClass()
                       {
                           Reference = this.Reference.Copy()
                       }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Of course, those will have to implement a `Copy()` method, too.